# How should I design my RESTful API in this case?

Tags: api, rest, endpoint

I've got a DB with a lot of people of type (PLAYER, DOCTOR, TEACHER) where each person has an ID and location ID. There're some common fields like `first name`, `last name` but also some fields that are specific on person's occupation: `number of injuries / the most serious injury type` for PLAYER, `number of patients` for DOCTOR and `can_teach_math` for TEACHER.

I want to build an API to compute total compensation of all these people that accepts a list of IDs (optional), list of location IDs (optional). For example, if someone passes 3 personIDm API should return a response with an array where each row corresponds to a specific person. If someone passes locationIDs - API should return all people who are living in that area.

Originally, I was thinking I could just return people ID:

```
request = {..., person_id:[person-123, person-456], location_id = [location-1, location-2]}

response = {
  [person_id:person-123, first_name=Alex, compensation=100],
  [person_id:person-456, first_name=Alex2, compensation=102],
  # anyone who lives in location-1, location-2
  [person_id:person-13, first_name=Alex3, compensation=50],
  [person_id:person-12, first_name=Alex4, compensation=52],
}
```

However UI engineer showed up and said they want to see

> also some fields that are specific on person's occupation: `number of injuries / the most serious injury type` for PLAYER, `number of patients` for DOCTOR and `can_teach_math` for TEACHER.

in a response even though it makes API denormalized. That said, it makes sense to me since loading all the object info through `GET persons/{ID}` might take quite a long time. Without going too much of the details, let's see we don't care about speed -- is the proper way to design RESTful API is not to return

> also some fields that are specific on person's occupation: `number of injuries / the most serious injury type` for PLAYER, `number of patients` for DOCTOR and `can_teach_math` for TEACHER.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I think it's language agnostic.